# Nginx Reverse Proxy for Tomcat Multiple App

Tags: nginx, tomcat, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a tomcat server, and 3 applications run under it. I want to serve them in their own domains using Nginx Reverse proxy, but I couldn't configure it.

Example:

`https://api.example.com > localhost:8081/api`

`https://data.example.com > localhost:8081/data`

Nginx Conf.

```
location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass          http://localhost:8081/api;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;
      sub_filter /api/ /;
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the URI path between NGINX and Tomcat can create many problems: e.g. many applications use absolute URI paths for associated resources (images, etc.). NGINX will not be able to rewrite them all.

Therefore I believe the best solution is to create several `<Host>`s on Tomcat:

```xml
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="api.example.com">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
           protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto" />
    <Host name="api.example.com"  appBase="webapps/api">
    ...
    </Host>
    <Host name="data.example.com"  appBase="webapps/data">
    ...
    </Host>
</Engine>
```

and deploy your applications under the name `ROOT.war` in either `webapps/api` or `webapps/data`. This way your NGINX configuration can look like:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass       http://localhost:8081;
}
```